# store integer value in controller to be used later by another method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

From my controller I am calling a view. Based on some parameters in the controller, certain sections in the view are generated.

Then in the view, I have a button which calls the controller back to create a pdf.

The pdf also has to show a certain section - based on the integer value. I am not able to do this.

My controller which calls the view:

```
    public ActionResult ActionForSubForm5()
        {               
            TempData["sform"] = 5;   
            return PartialView("_VoIPSubform");
        }
```

There are 7 methods like this in the controller which call the view with different Tempdata parameters.

Later in a totally different method calls the pdf generation part, I need that value 5.

```
   rcpt = Methods.CreateVoIPFormPDF(
                ....
                    VoIPSubformId,
                 ...
```

Is there a way I can store this value 5 for later use?

Comment: Normally you'd just pass this info to view, render and submit back... But that clearly not what you looking for (you may want to add why standard approach does not work in your case).

Comment: You can try passing that value to the view and use a `HiddenFieldFor` to store and when your view postbacks, you can use the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You should be sending the required values you need for generating the PDF, from the view which has the button to create pdf.

```
public ActionResult ActionForSubForm5()
{
    TempData["sform"] = 5;
    return PartialView("_VoIPSubform");
}
```

In your partial, keep the formId in a hidden variable so that when user submits the form, it will be available in the HttpPost action method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PrintPdf", "Home"))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="formId" value="@TempData["sform"]"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create PDF" />
}
```

The hidden field's `name` should match with your action method parameter name

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrintPdf(int formId)
{
    // to do :Generate PDF from the formId
}
```

> There are 7 methods like this in the controller which call the view
>   with different Tempdata parameters.

If it is 7 different methods, but all are setting different formIds to the PrintPdf method, you might better create a single action method which takes the formId value as a param

```
public ActionResult ActionForSubForm(int id)
{
    TempData["sform"] = id;
    return PartialView("_VoIPSubform");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Created a hiiden field and it works. Just had to modify the inline style a bit to make it appear in partial view. Otherwise it wasnt in the form.
<input type="input" style="visibility: hidden;" name="subform_ID" value=" <%:  TempData["sform"]  %> " /> <br />